# Bean Shell eval function implementation

Tags: java, android, beanshell

I want to evaluate regular expression in my project and want to use something similar to eval function of bean shell. Can anyone tell me implementation of eval function of Bean Shell?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your request is that there is not a single `eval` method that implements it, but a lot of methods spread throughout the `bsh` package. If I were you, I'd start at [`bsh.BSHBlock.eval(...)`](https://github.com/pejobo/beanshell2/blob/master/src/bsh/BSHBlock.java#L59) and follow the code.